# Cleartext HTTP traffic to mypage.com not permitted

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I know this question is asket a lot of times.
I'm using Api 28. I added this code in AndroidManifest.xml:

`<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"></application>`

In xml/network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">mypage.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Also tested on older API(Api 22) working, i get data from hosted Api(HTTP). Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using API 28+ please refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic) document.

You will see that since API 28 the value `android:usesCleartextTraffic` now defaults to false.

In your android manifest remove the xml you have previously written and simply use:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest ...>
        <application
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
            ...>
            ...
        </application>
    </manifest>
    ...
```

Comment: Added, same error again @JamesMallon